# Error import pylab in python 2.5

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, python-2.5

I tried to run this simple program on python 2.5 and get the following error, I am not sure what is going on.

Code:

```
import pylab
pylab.figure(1) # make figure 1 the current figure
pylab.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,7,3,5]) # draw on figure 1
pylab.show() # show figure on screen
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebastiancarrasco/Desktop/Courses/6.00.2x/Week1/plotting-seg1.py", line 3, in <module>
    pylab.figure(1) # make figure 1 the current figure
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 270, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 85, in new_figure_manager
    figManager = FigureManagerTkAgg(canvas, num, window)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 403, in __init__
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, self.window )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 670, in __init__
    NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, canvas)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2273, in __init__
    self._init_toolbar()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 719, in _init_toolbar
    command=self.home)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 702, in _Button
    im = Tk.PhotoImage(master=self, file=file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3294, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3250, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/images/home.ppm": permission denied
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like your user has permission to open `home.ppm` file.  You'll probably have to install matplotlib module for your user separately or install it inside a python virtual environment.

Comment: You are also using a mac which are notoriously unfriendly about installing the scientific python stack.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this problem and comes across this page: I eventually found the answer [here](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Re-Permission-error-after-installing-MPL-1-0-on-Mac-td12417.html). Long story short: some problem with the installer messes up the permissions for all the files in the "images" folder. All you have to do is change the permissions to give yourself read privileges.